# Prime Integer but not Gaussian Prime Proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is a prime integer and $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$, then $p$ is not a Gaussian prime.

How do I go about proving this?

I considered writing $p = k^2 + 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and factoring $p$ like this, but then I realized $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$ does not imply that $p - 1 = k^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that a prime $p$ is a Gaussian prime if and only if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. We will show that in this case, $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. The proof is the following:
$$\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1 \Leftrightarrow (-1)^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \Leftrightarrow \frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{p-1}{2} = 2k, \; k \in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow \\p=4k+1 \Leftrightarrow p \equiv 1 \pmod{4} $$

This proves that $p$ although a prime integer, cannot be a Gaussian prime.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, to prove that no prime $p$ such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ can be a Gaussian prime we can use Fermat's theorem on sum of two squares which states that a prime number $p$ can be expressed in the form $p = x^2+y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. In our case we can write $p=x^2+y^2$ and notice that $p = (x+iy)(x-iy)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean Domain the prime elements are exactly the irreducible ones and since $x\pm iy$ are not units we get that $p$ is not irreducible and hence not a Gaussian prime.

Comment: I'm supposed to do this without knowing that $p$ is a Gaussian prime iff $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: I will edit my answer!

Comment: @math_fan39170 Are you familiar with Fermat's theorem on sum of two squares?

Comment: yes, I am familiar with this

Comment: @math_fan39170 I have edited my answer and given an alternative way to prove it just with knowledge of Fermat's theorem on sum of two squares.